# Unix Shell Nested For Loop - syntax error

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop, unix, awk

INPUT FILE FORMAT

```
T12345670|1966-04-21|A01|1922-04-21|somebody name    | |9999-01-01| 
|CSGE|P175           |AGENT    |AMGDHR01|1977-04-21|1977-04-21|2018-10-05|1977-04-21|0001-01-01|          |          |2018-11-01|2019-04-21| 2019.|01|D|M|PMI |D|0|N| 1
.| 1.|N| 1.| 1.|0|       |   ||N|0001-01-01|   | 000000143.04| 000000075.00| 000000011.92| 000000011.92| 000000011.92| 000000034.14| 000000066.97| 000000130.04| 000005946.16|0|2018-10-05| 000000000.00|Y|2018-10-24|2018-10-23|499| 01.|||
```

I am trying to fix a syntax error.  The following code prints the output just right.

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS=", " '{$61!=""} {k=substr($61,1,1); ks[k]; c[k,length($61)]++} END {for(k in ks) print k": "c[k,0],c[k,1],c[k,2],c[k,3],c[k,4],c[k,5],c[k,6],c[k,7],c[k,8],c[k,9],c[k,10],c[k,11],c[k,12],c[k,13],c[k,14],c[k,15]}' The_File.sqf | sort
```

Prints this:

```
0: , , , , , , , , , , 2010, , , , , 3010
1: , , , , , , , , , , 40, , , , , 44
3: , , , , , , , , , , 5, , , , , 1
4: , , , , , , , , , , 6, , , , , 3
5: , , , , , , , , , , 212, , , , , 92
7: , , , , , , , , , , 79, , , , ,
8: , , , , , , , , , , 966, , , , ,
: 1279330, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
C: , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2198
```

Cool, right?

QUESTION: now I am trying to clean that code up by using a NESTED FOR LOOP but I get a syntax error after trying many variations.

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS=", " '{$61!=""} {k=substr($61,1,1); ks[k]; c[k,length($61)]++} END {for(k in ks); do for(i in {1..15}); do print k": " c[k,i]}; done; done' TheFile.sqf | sort
```

ERROR:

```
The error context is
            {$61!=""} {k=substr($61,1,1); ks[k]; c[k,length($61)]++} END {for(k in ks); do for(i in >>>  { <<<
```

Comment: This works: for i in {1..3}; do for j in {0..1}; do echo i; done; done ---------  Just trying to implement that structure with my code.

Comment: You are still in awk script there, not in bash. Did you mean to close the `'` quoting? The `for ... ;do ... ;done` syntax is bash syntax, not awk syntax.

Comment: I'll take a look.  Now I will try to compose a nested for in awk ....  I guess ... or should I switch to bash?

Comment: `awk` uses like `for (initialization; condition; increment) { statement1; statement2; }`. `awk` uses braces `{` `}` to group expressions in `for` or `while` or `if`'s.  The braces `{` `}` may be omitted, if there is only one expression `for (i=0;i<5;++i) print i;` See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html)...

Comment: I'll give that a try now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I fixed it for you  `{$61!=""}` doesn't mean anything, so removed.

```
$ awk -F'|' '{k=substr($61,1,1); ks[k]; 
              c[k,length($61)]++} 
         END {for(k in ks)
                {printf "%s: ", k;
                 for(i=1;i<=15;i++) printf ", %d", c[k,i];
                 print ""}}' file | sort
```

Comment: The error context is
                                 print >>>  ""} <<<

Comment: added missing brace.

Comment: Very close, I just did this to get the NULL values for(i=0